# Unresolved external symbols when compiling s_client from openssl library

Tags: openssl, unresolved-external

I am trying to build the utility "s_client" in openssl package (Windows, C++, Visual Studio 2019). 
 Unfortunately I have got "LINK2019 2001" errors - the linker couldn't find external symbols - **bio_err**, **psk_key**, **default_config_file**, and I couldn't find a source where it defined to add this module manually to my project and compile it.
 Could you help me - where they are defined ?

Comment: What command are you using to compile? It seems that you aren't linking to openssl.

Comment: @Michael M., I used a command "Build project" in VS2019. Path to the openssl libraries is set right. Then I pointed the linker to openssl libraries by: #pragma comment(lib, "libcrypto.lib") and #pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib"). For all needed modules in "apps" folder I created separate project that produced my copy of "apps" library. I did it because of after adding 2 pragma's, mentioned above, I got more than 100 linker errors. Most of them I have fixed, but mentioned above symbols I couldn't find.

Comment: @Michael M., when I just started linking and got many error I thought similar - may be I linked incorrectly, but in that time I hadn't any good idea about reason and hot to solve it.